# В каком формате хранить дату в БД?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть бд на MYSQL. В каком формате лучше хранить дату для дальнейших манипуляций с ней. Какие минусы, если хранить в `timestamp`. Какие минусы в `Date`.

Comment: Речь идет только о дате или о связке дата+время?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DATETIME**

Хранит время в виде целого числа вида YYYYMMDDHHMMSS, используя для этого 8 байтов. Это время не зависит от временной зоны. Оно всегда отображается при выборке точно так же, как было сохранено, независимо от того какой часовой пояс установлен в MySQL.

**TIMESTAMP**

Хранит 4-байтное целое число, равное количеству секунд, прошедших с полуночи 1 января 1970 года по усреднённому времени Гринвича (т.е. нулевой часовой пояс, точка отсчёта часовых поясов). При получении из базы отображается с учётом часового пояса. Часовой пояс может быть задан в операционной системе, глобальных настройках MySQL или в конкретной сессии. Запомните, что сохраняется всегда количество секунд по UTC (универсальное координированное время, солнечное время на меридиане Гринвича), а не по локальному часовому поясу

[Подробнее](http://habrahabr.ru/post/61391/)

Answer (score 2):

*Дату* надо хранить в формате date. Все другие варианты для этого типа данных не подходят.

Для понимания этого факта надо знать значение слова "дата", и чем оно отличается от слова "время".

Comment: А почему бы не timestamp в `INT UNSIGNED`?)

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно только выводить дату, тогда **DATETIME**.
Если же вам нужно манипулировать этой датой, что-то высчитывать, тогда однозначно **TIMESTAMP**.Лично склоняюсь в пользу **TIMESTAMP**

Answer (score 0):

Однозначного ответа нет. Но по сложившейся практике в `date` обычно хранят даты наподобии дня рождения, дня праздника и т.д. (т.е. который в целом фиксированы и не претерпят изменений), а в `timestamp` - дату добавления новости, дату просмотра текста и т.д.

Кроме того, надо понимать, что с `timestamp` легче работать, если придется периодически сравнивать, вычитать/прибавлять время или, допустим, запрашивать данные за последние сутки: `date - 60*60*24`